# Rails - search form returns error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

appreciate if you can help. I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and trying to make search form for imaginary site for a gym.

On each page I have a search form with code:

```
  <%= form_tag "/client_workouts/find" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>
```

my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :client_workouts

  post 'client_workouts/find' => 'client_workouts#find'
end
```

my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161103044039) do

  create_table "client_workouts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "client_name"
    t.string   "trainer"
    t.integer  "duration_mins"
    t.date     "date_of_workout"
    t.decimal  "paid_amount"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

end
```

and my scaffolded client_workouts_controller.rb (which 'def find' I edited to make search form work):

```
class ClientWorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_client_workout, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def find
    @client_workouts = ClientWorkout.find(:all, 
      :conditions=>["client_name = ? OR trainer = ?", params[:search_string], params[:search_string]])
  end

  # GET /client_workouts
  # GET /client_workouts.json
  def index
    @client_workouts = ClientWorkout.all
  end

  # GET /client_workouts/1
  # GET /client_workouts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /client_workouts/new
  def new
    @client_workout = ClientWorkout.new
  end

  # GET /client_workouts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /client_workouts
  # POST /client_workouts.json
  def create
    @client_workout = ClientWorkout.new(client_workout_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client_workout.save
        format.html { redirect_to @client_workout, notice: 'Client workout was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client_workout }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @client_workout.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /client_workouts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /client_workouts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @client_workout.update(client_workout_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @client_workout, notice: 'Client workout was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @client_workout }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @client_workout.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /client_workouts/1
  # DELETE /client_workouts/1.json
  def destroy
    @client_workout.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to client_workouts_url, notice: 'Client workout was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_client_workout
      @client_workout = ClientWorkout.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def client_workout_params
      params.require(:client_workout).permit(:client_name, :trainer, :duration_mins, :date_of_workout, :paid_amount)
    end
end
```

But when I trying to find something through the form I get:

```
Couldn't find all ClientWorkouts with 'id': 
(all, {:conditions=>["client_name = ? OR trainer = ?", "lol", "lol"]}) 
(found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

Extracted source (around line #5):
  def find
    @client_workouts = ClientWorkout.find(:all, 
      :conditions=>["client_name = ? OR trainer = ?",
 params[:search_string], params[:search_string]])
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like

```
ClientWorkout.where("client_name LIKE ? OR trainer LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search_string]}%", "%#{params[:search_string]}%")
```

Also, `Find` is a Method from `ActiveRecord` which accepts either `id` or `ids` or the `object` to find record. It also accepts `collection` of `ids` to return records from table. The way you have written the query, is probably not right.

I would suggest checking out this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and If you have just started to learn Rails
then I would strongly recommend reading some books like Crafting Rails and others in parallel. all the best

Comment: It worked, thanks! I'm little confused because I get my code from OReilly Head First Rails book, but thanks for advice about new books. :)

Comment: I am glad it worked. not sure why it has been written like this in the book but for sure checkout Crafting Rails book and you will learn really awesome stuffs.